# Showing that a space is Banach

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I've been given the following problem to solve:

Let $X$ be the space of all functions on $[0,1]$ which vanish at all but a countable number of points and for which
\begin{align}
\| x \|= \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x(t_n)| < \infty,
\end{align}
where $t_n$ are the points at which $x$ doesn't vanish.

I'd appreciate a **hint** on how to proceed to show that the space is complete. That is, that every Cauchy sequence converges to a function in this space.

Comment: This is the space $\ell_1[0,1]$. The proof for its completeness should be similar to the proof of completeness of $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$ (typically denoted, simply, $\ell_1$).

Comment: hint: a normed space is complete if and only if when $\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\|f_n\|<\infty $ then $\sum_{n\geqslant }f_n$ converges, for any sequence $(f_n)$

Comment: If you've proven $l_1$ spaces are complete in general, you can apply that fact to the [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure), where integrals become sums.

Comment: The assumption that the functions have countable support is superfluous: If $\sum\limits_{t\in [0,1]}|x(t)|$ (defined as the supremum of all finite sums) is finite then the support of $x$ is countable because, for every $n\in\mathbb N$, the set $\{t\in [0,1]: |x(t)|\ge 1/n\}$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the first thing to do is start with an arbitrary Cauchy sequence $x_n \in X$, and **construct** a limit $x \in X$ from it. You need to think about:

1. How to construct a function $x$ from the sequence $x_n$,
2. How to prove this constructed function $x$ lies in $X$, and
3. How to prove that $x_n \to x$.

For 1, make a guess, using the completeness of $\Bbb{R}$ (i.e. using Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb{R}$), as to what $x$ should do to an arbitrary $t \in [0, 1]$.

For 2, take your construction from part 1, and use the fact that, if you union all the points $t \in [0, 1]$ where $x_n(t) \neq 0$ for some $n$, this is still a countable set.

For 3, well, it's hard to give a hint without spoiling 1. Just try using the definitions.